# Load sample data after installation

Tags: contacts

I forgot to tick the box to install the sample data. Is there a way to do it after installation? I tried loading civicrm_sample.mysql but that didn't seem to load everything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it's a new install it might be simplest to just drop/recreate the database, remove the civicrm.settings.php file, and run the installer again.

The file with the sample data is sql/civicrm_generated.mysql, but it overlaps with sql/civicrm_data.mysql. You either use one or the other. If you just import the `generated` file now you'd get conflicts/duplicates for things like phone types etc.

Comment: I did just reinstall. I hadn't gone through all the configuration yet.